# Linkedin API - Captura de informações do perfil

Tags: php, api

Boa tarde. 
Bom, a minha dúvida é capturar informações do perfil de usuário do linkedin com PHP. Tentei mas só consigo retornar pra SESSION o firstname, lastname e aimagem da conta .

`$response = $OBJ_linkedin->profile('~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url)');`

quais são os parâmetros necessários para o **response** para obter por exemplo o email do usiuario.

Comment: Acredito, que no caso específico do email depende muito do usuário, porque ele pode ser visível ou não dependendo das configurações do usuário do linkedin. De qualquer forma eu testei por aqui https://apigee.com/console/linkedin